# Deactivating trigger doesn't work

Tags: sql, firebird, database-trigger

I am using the following code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER DBASIGNACION_NOTIFICACIONES INACTIVE;

INSERT INTO DBASIGNACION (CODREPARACION, CODPROYECTO, RECURSO, TIPO, ESTADO)
VALUES (123,null, 25, 1, 'A');

ALTER TRIGGER DBASIGNACION_NOTIFICACIONES ACTIVE;
```

The code of the trigger

```
SET TERM ^ ;
    ALTER TRIGGER DBASIGNACION_NOTIFICACIONES ACTIVE
    AFTER INSERT POSITION 0
AS 
    DECLARE VARIABLE codAsignacion INTEGER;
    DECLARE VARIABLE idNotificacion INTEGER;
BEGIN 
    idNotificacion = GEN_ID(gen_notificationsID,1);
    codAsignacion = NEW.CODASIGNACION;
    insert into DBNOTIFICACIONES (IDNOTIFICAION, IDASIGNACION) values 
        (:idNotificacion, :codAsignacion); 
END^
SET TERM ; ^
```

But when I insert whit the upside code the trigger is still active.

Do I need to create a procedure to make the trigger INACTIVE?

Comment: Did you commit the `ALTER TRIGGER...` statement before executing `INSERT`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set it to INACTIVE.

```
 ALTER TRIGGER trigger_name INACTIVE;
```

and then commit the transaction (changes).

```
 COMMIT;
```